# Have any fluids been vented directly from a rocket on a launchpad, instead of through an umbilical?

Tags: rockets, launchpad

Rockets on the launchpad often need to release liquids or gases before launch.  For example, cryogenic liquids boil off; the vapors need to be released to prevent tanks from bursting.  It seems that such fluids are typically removed from the rocket through an umbilical.  For the [shuttle](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36344/26446), boiled-off oxygen was removed at the "beanie cap", and boiled-off hydrogen came out through the hydrogen vent arm.

**Are there any examples where fluids were released from a rocket directly to the air or surroundings, instead of through an umbilical?**

The question is about rockets on the launchpad.  Rocket exhaust and urine dumps in space might technically be direct releases of fluids, but such things are not the scope of this question.

(I suspect that releasing cryogenic vapors would caused undesired condensation and icing on the rocket, but releases of other fluids seem plausible.)

Comment: You probably want to exclude [unintended leaks](https://aerospacenerd.com/2020/08/10/lessons-learnt-first-flight-slv-3/#The_Final_Partially_Unsuccessful_Launch_A_lesson_from_the_Failure). ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saturn V vented GOX directly to the atmosphere during countdown.  Watch any Apollo countdown video such as [Apollo 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3ufJ7lcr08).

The [Apollo 12 SA507 reference manual](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap12fj/pdf/a12_sa507-flightmanual.pdf) mentions propellant venting on pages 4-12 (S-IC "Prior to launch, boil off in the lox tank may be harmlessly vented overboard"), 5-15 (S-II "The tanks are vented by opening the tank vent valves, two per propellant tank, to allow ullage gas to escape from the tanks"), 6-13 (S-IV "The lox tank is vented through its propulsive vent duct, located in the aft skirt, during loading").

Answer (score 4):

The payload fairings (containing the payload) are supplied with cool dry air while the rocket is on the launch pad. I doubt whether two hoses are ever provided; one for the air to enter and the other for the air to leave the fairing. There doesn't seem to be any reason why the air couldn't just vent through vent holes in the fairing.

I went through a few user guides.

1. [DeltaII](https://ula.bsshost.me/docs/default-source/rockets/deltaiipayloadplannersguide2007.pdf#page=92)

> Air-conditioning  is  supplied  to  the  spacecraft  via  an  umbilical  after  the  payload  fairing  is  mated to the launch vehicle. The payload air-distribution system (Figure 4-1) provides air at the required temperature, ... The  air  flows  downward  around  the  spacecraft  and  is  discharged  below  the  second  stage  through  **vents  in  the  interstage**.

2. Long March 3A. [This one has a diagram](http://www.cgwic.com/launchservices/download/manual/Chapter%206%20Environmental%20Conditions.pdf#page=4) with two arrows leaving the fairing hinting that the air pumped in for air conditioning is just vented out.

Comment: Nothing exotic about this answer :) Just plain air (or nitrogen).